# How to share screen remotely in a video/audio call?

Tags: android, webrtc, screensharing, android-mediaprojection

I am trying to build a video call app which has a feature of screen sharing. The users can share their screen during the call. I'm using `WebRTC` SDK to meet my purpose, but they have a solution for screen share when the call starts but not for screen share while the call is ongoing. One can tick the screen sharing option and can start the call but cannot start screen sharing during the call.

I added a button on the CallActivity screen which on click calls MediaProjection Class of Android to cast the screen but the casted screen is not being shown remotly.

```
public void onScreenShare(boolean isScreenShared) {
    screencaptureEnabled = isScreenShared;
    if (screencaptureEnabled && videoWidth == 0 && videoHeight == 0) {
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getDisplayMetrics();
        videoWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
        videoHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
    }

    if (isPemitted()) {
        startScreenCapture();
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "onScreenShare: not permitted");
    }

    /*if (peerConnectionClient != null) {
        peerConnectionClient.stopVideoSource();
    }*/
}

private void startScreenCapture() {
    MediaProjectionManager mediaProjectionManager =
            (MediaProjectionManager) getApplication().getSystemService(
                    Context.MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE);
    startActivityForResult(
            mediaProjectionManager.createScreenCaptureIntent(), 
CAPTURE_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    Log.d("tagged", ">>>>Method called :- ");
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
    Log.d("tagged", ">>>>Method called :- " + requestCode);
    if (requestCode != CAPTURE_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE)
        return;
    else {
        mediaProjectionPermissionResultCode = resultCode;
        mediaProjectionPermissionResultData = data;

if (peerConnectionParameters.videoCallEnabled) {
        videoCapturer = createVideoCapturer();
    }
    peerConnectionClient.createPeerConnection(
            localProxyVideoSink, remoteSinks, videoCapturer, 
 signalingParameters);
    }
}

private @Nullable
VideoCapturer createScreenCapturer() {
    Log.d("CheckMedia", ">>>Checking " + 
mediaProjectionPermissionResultData);
    if (mediaProjectionPermissionResultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        reportError("User didn't give permission to capture the screen.");
        return null;
    }
    return new ScreenCapturerAndroid(
            mediaProjectionPermissionResultData, new 
MediaProjection.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onStop() {
            reportError("User revoked permission to capture the screen.");
        }
    });
}
```

This code starts the casting on local device but is not streaming anything on remote device.

**UPDATE**

```
 private void switchCameraInternal() {
    if (videoCapturer instanceof CameraVideoCapturer) {
        if (!isVideoCallEnabled() || isError) {
            Log.e(TAG,
                    "Failed to switch camera. Video: " + 
 isVideoCallEnabled() + ". Error : " + isError);
            return; // No video is sent or only one camera is available or 
 error happened.
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "Switch camera");
        CameraVideoCapturer cameraVideoCapturer = (CameraVideoCapturer) 
 videoCapturer;
        cameraVideoCapturer.switchCamera(null);

    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "Will not switch camera, video caputurer is not a 
camera");
    }
 }

public void switchCamera() {
    executor.execute(this::switchCameraInternal);
}

private void startScreenSharing() {
    if (videoCapturer instanceof ScreenCapturerAndroid) {
        if (!isVideoCallEnabled() || isError) {
            Log.e(TAG,
                    "Failed to share screen. Video: " + isVideoCallEnabled() 
+ ". Error : " + isError);
            return; // No video is sent or only one camera is available or 
error happened.
        }
        ScreenCapturerAndroid screenCapturerAndroid = 
(ScreenCapturerAndroid) videoCapturer;
        screenCapturerAndroid.startCapture(500, 500, 30);
    }
}

public void screenSharing() {
    executor.execute(this::startScreenSharing);
}
```

> I did the changes, and made the code look similar to switchCamera()
>   code but I am getting an Not On Camera Thread Exception.

Comment: You mentioned that the sharing is working fine if you don't start video first so there is no need to change anything apart from removing the video track before adding the new one. Check my update

Comment: [Reference](https://github.com/duttaime/WebRTCAndroid) Still not able to make it. Can you help me out here, actually trying this from past 5 days now.

Comment: You can check my code example and fit it to your needs

Comment: @113408 I am stuck in the same situation as mentioned above.
It will be really helpful if i could get the link your code to fit my need.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can stream from the **Camera** and **Screen** at the same time. However what you can do is:

1. User click the screen share button
2. You remove your **Camera** video track from your `PeerConnection` using `PeerConnection.removeTrack(RtpSender sender)`
3. You create your **Screen** video track using `ScreenCapturerAndroid` (as you already do)
4. You add the track to your `PeerConnection`

If you say that the Screen share is working without call then step 4 and 5 should already be done.

Don't forget to dispose/release all resources related to the `Camera` when you remove its track.

Also to stop the **Screen** share and go back to the **Camera** just do the above steps for the **Screen** track.

For reference : [PeerConnection.java](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/+/HEAD/sdk/android/api/org/webrtc/PeerConnection.java)

**UPDATE :**

Here is a part of the WebRTC Client that allows me to achieve what you are asking for (you can adapt it to your current code base):

```
private fun stopCameraShare(){
        videoCapturerAndroid?.stopCapture()
        localRenderer.dispose()
        localVideoView.release()
        localVideoView.clearImage()
        stream?.removeTrack(localVideoTrack)
        localVideoTrack.dispose()
    }
private fun shareScreen(){
        stopCameraShare()
        val mediaProjectionManager = activity!!.getSystemService(Context.MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE) as MediaProjectionManager
        startActivityForResult(mediaProjectionManager.createScreenCaptureIntent(), 29)
    }

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        if (requestCode != 29)
            return
        initVideos()
        videoCapturerAndroid = ScreenCapturerAndroid(
            data, object : MediaProjection.Callback() {
                override fun onStop() {
                    Timber.e("User revoked permission to capture the screen.")
                }
            })
        peerConnectionFactory.setVideoHwAccelerationOptions(rootEglBase.eglBaseContext, rootEglBase.eglBaseContext)
        videoSource = peerConnectionFactory.createVideoSource(videoCapturerAndroid)
        localVideoTrack = peerConnectionFactory.createVideoTrack("100", videoSource)
        videoCapturerAndroid?.startCapture(300, 300, 30)
        stream?.addTrack(localVideoTrack)
    }
```

PS: It's very important to `peerConnectionFactory.setVideoHwAccelerationOptions(rootEglBase.eglBaseContext, rootEglBase.eglBaseContext)`

Hope this will help you !

Comment: We cannot stream from camera and screen, agreed. But I want to stop camera when screen sharing starts. Will follow your steps, have you done anything similar?

Comment: Yes we have a similar setup. If you implemented the camera switch(between front and back) then it’s mostly same

Comment: We are using PeerConnection.addTrack() and not MediaStream, any suggestion regarding this.

Comment: I'm using a probably different version of WebRTC as in my case, I create a `MediaStream` and give it the `AudioTrack` and `VideoTrack` then pass the said stream to `PeerConnection.addStream(MediaStream)`. What revision of WebRTC are you using ?

Comment: @113408..I have implemented the same and it works fine. But it stops after few minutes. I am getting : buffer queue has abundant. As error

Comment: @user2980181  I would suggest you create a separate question with stack trace of the error you get to have the help from the community

Comment: @user2980181 did you ever figure out that error? I am getting the same

Comment: @VismayPatil Did your screen-share works fine now along with the video call?
Seems like the reference link mentioned above doesn't have the screen share implementation.
Would be great if you could suggest something as your asked question is similar to my use case.

Comment: @Sunilkumar I moved on from this and using video conferencing sdk for example Twilio where just calling a method will allow me to share my screen without thinking about the internal logic.

Comment: @VismayPatil Thanks for your response.Any specific reason related performance or anything else regarding production use of WebRTC. Actually we are targeting to use this app in large audience Video Confernce. Whats your opinion on WebRTC performance?

Comment: Using WebRTC directly needs lot of things to be handled. It depends on your need whether you just want audio/video calling in your app or you want to create a platform like a wrapper around webRTC which can be used by others. If yours is the first case then I suggest you should choose some third party library who does all the webRTC handling on their side and provide you with necessary callbacks.

Comment: I need help in this since i can't find setVideoHwAccelerationOptions(rootEglBase.eglBaseContext, rootEglBase.eglBaseContext) method in peerconnectionfactory.

Comment: The method setVideoHwAccelerationOptions(rootEglBase.eglBaseContext, rootEglBase.eglBaseContext) has been removed (see my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63137545/webrtc-how-to-enable-hardware-acceleration-for-the-video-encoder). Do you know an alternative?